# What happens if you leave in between rounds of Snipers Vs Stunters (GTAV)

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Like the title says, let's say I make it up to round 3 of a snipers vs Stunters game. If I left the game right after that. Would I still get the cash that I've earned in the previous rounds?gta (I know that I'll get bad sport rep.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

Even if you leave in **between** rounds and not **during** one in a GTA online match, you will still have all the money and xp you gained **until that point**

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Also, I found out that you can store the money in your bank during a round.